# Find number of solution of diophantine equation

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations

How many integer solutions ( in terms of integer $a,b,c$) has the equation
$$
x \cdot y \cdot z =(a-x) (b-y) (c-z),
$$
here $x,y,z>0$ and $a-x,b-y,c-y>0$.

I can find  number of solutions for some values  $a,b,c$  but I hope there exists a formula   or a generating function.

Comment: $a=2x,b=2y,c=2z$ works, but there must be others. What solutions have you found?

Comment: No, $a,b,c$ are fixed constants, I am looking for $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 0):

For the solution of the equation.

$$xyz=(a-x)(b-y)(c-z)$$

Solution we write expanding on the multipliers. $c=qt$ And $sn=\frac{q-1}{2}$ ; $pk=\frac{q+1}{2}$

$$x=n(bp-as)$$

$$y=s(ak-bn)$$

$$z=tpk$$

Comment: Do we get all solutions under this  parametrisation?